# C language, serial port reader

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

I want to make a program that reads a serial port (V.24).
with the info from the serial port I need to split a string up, and add it to a MySQL database.

I don't know C very well, so I need some help with what functions I should use

The program has to run under windows XP, and I have to make it an service.

thanks,
Sebastian

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, he will have to learn C then, doesn't he?  I distinctly remember me wanting to program a Moon Lander clone in C, then I learned C and did it. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Services are a pain to debug.  I suggest writing your code as a normal application first - command line will do - and then, once it works, converting it to a service (which is a mechanical process).

In general, Windows GUI based apps in C are a PITA to write for the first time.  Very finicky, very sensitive.  A command line app or a service will be quite a bit easier.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that the only person who ever wrote a Windows GUI program from scratch was Petzold; everyone else took one of his programs as a basis.

Comment: @MSalters: heh, I claim that dubious honour =-)  Bitch it was too!  Windows does not tell you what's going wrong.  You just have to get it all right, then it magically works.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [reading this](http://www.robbayer.com/files/serial-win.pdf). As for if this will work as a service, I am not sure, but it should.

You can also look at [existing](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) open source projects, to see if you can take that source as a starting point, or if they already solve your problems.